# Rails adding external libs to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a rails app. I've extracted some common code out into a library under

```
APP_ROOT/lib/my_lib/my_lib.rb

APP_ROOT/lib/my_lib/version.rb
```

Currently my controllers can access the lib, but if I write a small standalone script in

```
APP_ROOT/lib/my_lib/test.rb
```

that looks like this:

```
require 'my_lib'
libtest = MyLib.new
```

I get a error:

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- my_lib (LoadError)
```

I've tried modifying LOAD_PATH, RUBYLIB to include this, but I can't seem to get it to find the library.

Comment: Dave, can you provide more details please? See a comment below...

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3/4 you simply need to update *config/application.rb*

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib/my_lib"
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to make a difference, but then I don't have a problem with the rails app loading the library - it does this successfully.  When I try to load the library from a script that is not part of the rails application, I get the problem

Comment: *I try to load the library from a script*, can you explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require './lib/my_lib/my_lib.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your custom lib i.e.

```
my_lib.rb
```

and it's in a folder called `my_lib`. When you try to require a lib like:

```
require 'name_of _the_lib.rb'
```

the server looks for the file in the `lib` folder which is in `APP_ROOT`. So, now you have to mention your `my_lib` folder too like this:

```
require 'my_lib/my_lib.rb'
```

Hope it will work.